# Why is $\emptyset \in \{N \subseteq \mathcal{X}|\exists E\in \mathbb{E} \text{ such that } N \subseteq E \text{ and } \mu(E)=0\}$?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\mathcal{X},\mathbb{E},\mu)$ be a measure space

My textbook says that the emptyset is in the paving:

$\emptyset \in \{N \subseteq \mathcal{X}|\exists E\in \mathbb{E} \text{ such that } N \subseteq E \text{ and } \mu(E)=0\}$

But I don't understand why. I see that $\emptyset \in \mathbb{E}$ because it is a sigma algebra

But I don't see why it should be in the set $\mathcal{X}$

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The theorem only states that the empty set is a subset of $\mathcal X$, not that it is an element

Answer (score 1):

You only need a set $E\in\Bbb E$ such that $\mu(E)=0$, because $\emptyset$ is a subset of every set.

Comment: Ok. It also states that the same goes for every $E \in \mathbb{E}$. But every E is not in $\mathcal{X}$. Is this a similar argument?

Comment: @Daniel, by definition, $\mathbb{E}$ consists of subsets of $\mathcal{X}$, so E is a subset of $\mathcal{X}$. The claim in the textbook is that the empty set is in the paving of the measure space, where the paving is the collection of subsets of $\mathcal{X}$ that are also subsets of some set E with zero measure. This can be seen because the empty set is clearly a subset of itself, and one of the axioms of a measure space is that the measure of the empty set is zero.